# MonogDB connecting to my local computer from ubuntu vps server but not connecting to server's MonogDB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, ubuntu, vps

I am troubling some problems when I am trying to connect my Nodejs app with MongoDB on the ubuntu VPS server. It connecting to my local computer's database when I tried from my computer, but when I tried from my mobile it returns a network error. The web is completely working well on localhost and on the server with my local computer's database. But not connecting with the server's database.
here is connection string: "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/dealerportal";

Comment: Rephrase your question. It's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is localhost - is that the only IP address the VPS server is listening on?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.